# How to calculate time for a cilk_spawn

Tags: c++, c, execution-time, gprof, cilk

thanks for looking at the post

I am benchmarking some Cilk Plus code and was looking to calculate the time required to complete a "spawn" operation. I am interested in calculating only the time required to do a spawn and not the computational time required by fib(). Is this possible to do ?

Will putting the timer in the following code work as expected ? If my thinking is correct will replacing the "// RRS" with timer_start() and timer_stop(), get the job done ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
int fib(int n)
{
  if (n < 2) return n;
  else {
  // RRS: Start timer t1 here ??
  int x = cilk_spawn fib(n-1);
  // RRS: Stop timer t1 here ??

  int y = fib(n-2);

  // RRS: Start timer t2 here ??       
  cilk_sync;
  // RRS: Stop timer t2 here ??

  return x + y;
  }
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int result = fib(n);
  printf("Fibonacci of %d is %d.\n", n, result);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I am able to put some timer start/stop statements in the comment lines "// RRS" and count time for spawn faithfully.

Thanks for attention.